# WKInterfaceController top right button

Tags: apple-watch, wkinterfacecontroller

On `WKInterfaceController`, is there a way to add a button (such as 'Done') at the top right corner of the watch screen instead of the time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can specify a 'title' for [a presented modal controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014957-CH1-SW22), but it will always appear on the top left corner.

> If the modal interface controller does not have a title, its title is set to the string Cancel by default. You can set the value of this string in your storyboard or change it at runtime using the setTitle: method. When the user taps the title string, WatchKit automatically dismisses the modal interface without taking any further actions.

Interestingly, Apple *does* happen to display Done on the right during modal text dictation.  You could [submit an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com/) asking to substitute a 'title' in place of the time.

[image]
[image]